# Are the Initiate of the Sevenfold Veil Class abilities vulnerable to Dispel Magic as well?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

I was Looking at the class abilities for Initiate of the Sevenfold Veil and I Saw how specific spells got through them much like a Prismatic Wall needing 7 different spells to get rid of it. I was wondering can each veil be dispelled by dispel magic or just by the spell in its entry. for example the orange veil being destroyed by a gust of wind spell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Only the *violet veil* is vulnerable to *dispel magic*.** The rest follow the rules of the prismatic spells, such as [prismatic wall](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/prismaticWall.htm).

Comment: This is very correct. Additionally, even if the ability it's based on (Prismatic Sphere, Prismatic Wall) HAD been vulnerable to dispels, the Initiate's wardings are a (Su) ability if I'm remembering correctly, and as such beyond the reach of dispel attempts.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I would like to point out that it hinges on interpreting the "These veils duplicate the layers of a prismatic wall" clause as the warding as a whole being negatable as a Prismatic Wall only.

@Lord_Gareth The Wardings are a SLA, and would thus be subject to normal dispelling if it were not for the clause.

Comment: I stand corrected, thank'ee kindly. It's been a bit since I got a close look at the class - my CompArc's 900 miles away.